# Is this an valid example from python's smtplib?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Is this an valid example from Python's `smtplib`? How,  from this example, would one send email without giving the password?

```
import smtplib

def prompt(prompt):
    return raw_input(prompt).strip()

fromaddr = prompt("From: ")
toaddrs  = prompt("To: ").split()
print "Enter message, end with ^D (Unix) or ^Z (Windows):"

# Add the From: and To: headers at the start!
msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\n\r\n"
       % (fromaddr, ", ".join(toaddrs)))
while 1:
    try:
        line = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    if not line:
        break
    msg = msg + line

print "Message length is " + repr(len(msg))

server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: You have to grant permissions to your server in the SMTP server in order to successfully send a mail.

Answer (score -1):

You can send emails without using a password assuming the server configuration allow that.